# Inheritance of abstract methods with package access

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

According section "8.1.1.1" of JLS we have:

A class C has abstract methods if either of the following is true:

• Any of the member methods (§8.2) of C - either declared or inherited - is
abstract.

• Any of C's superclasses has an abstract method declared with package access,
and there exists no method that overrides the abstract method from C or from
a superclass of C

It is interesting, why do we have second option here. In particular, why do we have exactly "package access". And what about "public" or "protected" methods?

Comment: It's basically saying that your class is abstract until you provide concrete implementations for all your abstract methods (methods explicit in your class, or implicit from parent classes).  Remember: "package scope" is when you *don't* specify "public" or "protected" or "private"; it's visible anywhere inside the package, and not visible outside of the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From order of most private to most open, the java modifiers go:

- private
- package
- protected
- public

Child classes cannot inherit the package methods of a parent class in another package. So a class inheriting from a such a parent would not be abstract according to rule 1. Therefore the 2nd rule exists to address the situation where a child class inherits from an abstract parent and is unable to provide an implementation of the abstract package methods.

It's a nonsensical situation, and I would never expect to see this in any program anywhere. But the language must be fully specified or you could end up with a weird bug that allows a class with undefined methods to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The likely meaning of this is that `protected` and `public` are also declarations that provide package access. `private` methods are not, and they also cannot be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you are right.
The second option concerns only one particular case:
particular subclass is in a different package than its superclass.

For example,

```
package superpackage;

public abstract class SuperFoo {
    abstract void foo();
}


package subpackage;

import superpackage.SuperFoo;

public abstract class SubFoo extends SuperFoo {}
```

Please note that this class should be declared abstract, otherwise we have compilation error.

In this particular case we do not have "inheritance of foo method" as inheritance requires
that SubFoo class be in the same package as SuperFoo.
see section 8.4.8 in JLS for more details.

Nevertheless, this class still contains "foo" method (by definition) and hence should be marked with abstract keyword.

Further, we can extend our SubFoo class by another concrete class that belongs to "superpackage" package.

For example,

```
package subclass;

import subpackage.SubFoo;

public class SecondSubFoo extends SubFoo {
    @Override
    void foo() {}
}
```

Note:

1) The fact is that public and protected methods fall into first item of definition as they are inherited and there is no need second item of definition for them.

2) Package access methods are also fall into first item of definition if they are in the same package and hence there is no need second item of definition for them too.

3) On the other hand, package access methods that are in the other package do not fall into first item of definition as they are not inherited (see the definition of inheritance of abstract methods in section 8.4.8 of JSL) and hence they are required second item of definition.